# what powdered fungicide is equivalent to captan 50

Tags: trees, fruit-trees

The spray I use for apple trees is a combination of imidan and captan 50.  I find that captan is no longer available.  What powder fungicide can I buy that is effective as captan?

Comment: Please add your country into the question. Laws and availability vary from one jurisdiction to another.

Comment: Neenah, Wisconsin USA